# Argument for the diameter of these 2 graphs...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

[image: 2 graphs question focusing on the diameter of the 2 graphs]

I believe G1 has a diameter of 2 & G2 has a diameter of 4.

However, is there a formal way to prove / argue for these given diameters? I'd like to see an argument without having to list all the possible distances (between any 2 nodes) & then concluding what the diameter must be.

Comment: Well, symmetry helps a lot with the first one (you only have to analyze two nodes!  All the others follow by rotation).  the second one is certainly harder.  But there are so few nodes...is the problem that you don't trust the enumeration?  That you fear that you failed to spot a shorter path?

Comment: I believe those are the diameters; I'm just interested in seeing how one makes an argument for why those are the diameters. I believe I already have a sufficient one. I described the nature of moving between / amongst the "outside" and "inside" vertices in one form or another & how the symmetry of the graph allows for a diameter of 2. Also, I noted that the diameter of 4 for G2 is a consequence of how the diagonals run to node 11.

Answer (score 1):

**First graph.**

For the first graph here is how you can take advantage of the symmetry:

**Remark 1:** By rotating the outside you get another copy of the same graph, with any outside node you desire instead of 1.

**Remark 2:** You can redraw the graph with $6-8-10-7-9$ as the outside cycle, and $1-2-3-4-5$ as the star inside. Then you get another copy of the same graph.

These two remarks allow you to redraw the graph in such a way that it looks the same and any node you desire is in the place of node 1. Formally, this proves that for any two nodes $u,v$ there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $\sigma(u)=v$.

**Proof that the diameter is 2:**

Since $d(1,3)=2$ it follows that $d(G) \geq 2$. To prove equality, we need to show that for all $u,v \in V(G)$ we have $d(u,v) \leq 2$.

By the above we can redraw the graph in such a way that $u$ is instead of node 1. Thus, we only need to show that for all $w$ we have 
$$d(1,w) \leq 2$$

Case 1: $w$ is outside vertex. This is easy, you can either enumerate (using the symmetry from case 2) or use the fact that the diameter of the cycle $C_5$ is 2.

case 2: $w$ is an inside vertex.

Note that the graph is invariant under reflection in the line passing through vertices 1 and 6. This reflection takes 10 to 7, 9 to 8.

If w is 10 or 9, use the reflection. Therefore, we can assume $w \in \{ 6, , 7, 8\}$. Calculate all three distances.

**Second graph**

First, it is easy to see that $d(1,11)=4$.

Next, look at the cycles
$$1-2-7-8-9-11-6-10-5-1$$

the diameter of this cycle is $4$, which shows that the distance between any two vertices on this cycle is at most $4$.

This leaves you with proving that $d(3,w) \leq 4$ and $d(4,w) \leq 4$ for all $w$.

Now, do the same with the cycles
$$3-2-1-5-10-6-11-9-4-3$$
and 
$$3-2-7-8-9-4-3$$

Now matter what $w$ is, it belongs to one of the two cycles.